# Windows command line - How to delete a file named in a textfile?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to delete a file whose name is stored in a textfile. I can set a variable to the name in this textfile using the command:

```
set /p "fileToDelete="<textFile.txt
```

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to delete the file with the name of this fileToDelete variable. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it would help us if you showed us how you attempted to use the `DEL` command with the environmental variable you created? We would also need to know what the contents of the text file is.

Comment: just add the next line `del /Q "%filetodelete%"`. This is also assuming there is only one line in that file.

Comment: …or `Del /A /F "%fileToDelete%"`, as the `/Q` option is not required when no wildcard is used! Open a Command Prompt window, type `del /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, to see its usage information.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, if it is a single line in `textfile.txt` then:

```
set /p "fileToDelete="<textFile.txt
del /Q ""fileToDelete%"
```

if multiple listed lines:

```
@for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("textfile.txt") do @del /Q "%%~i"
```

All that said, it will depend on where your files are located, if they are not in the root where the script is located or the full path is not specified in the file, then there are other things to consider.